# $\lambda$-commutativity and commutativity of operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $\mathcal{B}(F)$ the algebra of all bounded linear operators on an infinite-dimensional complex Hilbert $F$.

> Let $T,S\in\mathcal{B}(F)$. The pair $(T,S)$ is said to be $\lambda$-commute if there exists $\lambda\in \mathbb{C}^*$ such that $TS=\lambda ST$.

If $\lambda=1$, the operators $T$ and $S$ are commuting.

> There are of lot of pairs $T$ and $S$ which are $\lambda$-commute but they don't commute. It is possible to find a suitable conditions on $T$ and $S$ under which $\lambda$-commutativity implies commutativity?

Notice that in finite dimensional Hilbert spaces, since $tr(TS)=tr(ST)$, so if $tr(TS)$ is non-zero, then $\lambda=1$.

Comment: Who told you that $||TS||=||ST||$? In two dimensions, if $T(x,y)=(x+y,x+y)$ and $S(x,y)=(x-y,x-y)$ then $||ST||\ne||TS||$.

Comment: please see (Proposition 2.3.) of the follwoing paper: M. LAURA ARIAS, GUSTAVO CORACH and M. CELESTE GONZALEZ, Metric properties of
projections in semi-Hilbertian spaces, Integral Equations and Operator Theory, 62 (2008), pp.
11-28.

Comment: What does the proposition say?

Comment: It say that we have equality between the norms of $TS$ and $ST$.

Comment: No, it doesn't say that. You left out the _hypotheses_.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich The only hypothesis is that $T$  and $S$ are bounded.

Comment: I am looking at the paper right now and introducing all the notation used in the hypothesis necessary to merely read the relevant item in the proposition would not fit in this comment.

Comment: @Echan In particular it's not claimed for every bounded $S$ and $T$?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich  In (Proposition 2.3.) of the above paper, when $A=I$ we get $TS$ and $ST$ have the same norms.

Comment: @Schüler This is riidiculous, unless you're willing to say what the proposition actually asserts. A second you claimed  that it said that $ST$ and $TS$ have the same norm for _any_ bounded $S$ and $T$. If so there's no "$A$" there. WHAT DOES THE PROPOSITION SAY?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Proposition 2.3. say that if $T,S\in \mathcal{B}_A(F)$, then $\|TS\|_A=\|ST\|_A$ and when $A=I$ we have $$\|TS\|=\|ST\|.$$

Comment: What is $B_A$???

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich If $A\in \mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H})^{+}$ and $T\in \mathcal{L}_{A}(\mathcal{H})$ then if $W \in \mathcal{L}_{A}(\mathcal{H})$ $\lVert TW \rVert_{A} = \lVert WT\rVert_{A}$. Where $\mathcal{H}$ is a complex valued hilbert space, $\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H})$ are bounded linear operators on the space, $\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H})^{+}$ is the cone of all positive linear operators on $\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H})$. Finally for $T$ defined by $T\xi = \xi$, $T\eta = \eta$ $T(S) = \{0\}$, in $\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H})$, $\mathcal{L}_{A}(\mathcal{H})$ is the sub algebra of all $A$ adjoints of $T$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I think that is the best I can do given the space of the comments below, but that is the content of the paper that was referenced with the papers original notation.

Comment: @Echan: I think you are misreading the paper (although I agree that the Proposition could have been written more clearly). In Proposition 2.3, $W$ is not an arbitrary operator (note that it doesn't say so), but an $A$-adjoint of $T$. So the equality is the $A$-version of $\|T^*T\|=\|TT^*\|$.

Comment: @MartinArgerami You are right. Please see my edit.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich You are right $\|TS\|$ is not in general equal to $\|ST\|$. Thank you for your remark and I have edited my question.

Comment: Your trace comment is wrong, consider $T=\begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\0&0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $S=\begin{pmatrix} 0&0\\1&0 \end{pmatrix}$. Then $\operatorname{tr}(TS)=1=\operatorname{tr}(ST)$ *(which as you stated correctly holds in general as the trace is cyclic)* but $TS\neq ST$ and even worse, $(T,S)$ do not even $\lambda$-commute for any $\lambda\in\mathbb C\backslash\lbrace0\rbrace$.

Comment: @Frederikv.E. I see in finite dimentional if $T$ and $S$ are $\lambda$-commute and $tr(TS)$ is non-zero, then they commute.

Comment: I see, then your argument is correct. I first thought you meant that in finite dimensions, $\operatorname{tr}(ST)\neq 0$ automatically implies that $S$ and $T$ have to commute due to the cyclicity of the trace, my bad.

Comment: @Frederikv.E. there is no problem and thank you for your example

Comment: @MartinArgerami I'm having trouble understanding in what way I am misreading the paper because later in the same comment you say that $W$ is not an arbitrary operator; isn't that consistent with my comment saying that $W\in \mathcal{L}_{A}(\mathcal{H})$?

Comment: If you read the proof of Proposition 2.3.3, it starts with "If $W$ is an $A$-adjoint operator of $T$, then..." It looks very clear to me; even clearer is you read the statement of 2.3.2. Notwithstanding the fact that the equality $\|TS\|=\|ST\|$ fails even in $2\times2$ matrices.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Do you think that $S,T \geq 0$ or $S,T \leq 0$ is a sufficient condition for $S$ and $T$ to commute if they $\lambda$-commute?

Comment: Yes, both $S,T\geq0$ (or negative) is a sufficient condition.

Comment: @MartinArgerami But I explicitly said it was an $A$-adjoint of $T$. Are you confusing me with the OP?

Comment: You said that $W\in L_A(H)$; if I remember correctly (I'm not looking at the paper now), that's the unit $A$-ball; but it doesn't say that $W$ is an $A$-adjoint of $T$, which the Proposition uses.

Comment: @MartinArgerami I also said that, quoting directly from my comment yesterday "$\mathcal{L}_{A}(\mathcal{H})$ is the sub algebra of all $A$ adjoints of $T$". Nowhere did I say that it is the unit $A$-ball. Again, are you confusing me for OP? I feel like you are confusing me with a different person.

Comment: I don't know if I'm confusing you with someone else; I'm just answering to what you write. Your comment is wrong: $L_A(H)$ is the set of operators that admit an $A$-adjoint, not the set of adjoints of some fixed operator. It doesn't depend on a fixed  $T$; it only depends on $A$. What 2.3.3 is saying is that if an $A$-adjoint $W$ of $T$ happens to be $A$-adjointable, then $\|WT\|_A=\|TW\|_A$. As I already said, it's the $A$-version of $\|T^*T\|=\|TT^*\|$.

Comment: @MartinArgerami I see where the misunderstanding is now. Thanks.

Comment: @Schüler What do you mean by "suitable conditions"? Here are some sufficient conditions which I know: 1) $T,S$ bounded, self-adjoint, $\lambda$-commute, $\lambda\neq -1$ implies $T,S$ commute. 2) $T,S$ bounded, $T=S^*$, $T,S$ $\lambda$-commute implies $T,S$ commute.

Comment: @YuriiSavchuk I am looking for necessary and sufficient conditions on the operators $S$ and $T$ such that $(T,S)$ $\lambda$-commute, then they already commute.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Assume that $S,T \geq 0$ or $S,T \leq 0$. Since $S$ and $T$ are $\lambda$-commute then there exists $\lambda\in \mathbb{C}^*$ such that $TS=\lambda ST$ which implies that $TS=|\lambda|^2 TS$ and hence $|\lambda|=1$. But why $\lambda=1$?

Comment: Because the spectrum of $ TS $ is real.

Comment: @Schüler Do you have such conditions for matrices?

Comment: @YuriiSavchuk For matrices if $tr(TS)$ is non zero then we get the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea would be to consider Hilbert-Schmidt operators

$$
\mathcal B_2(\mathcal H)=\lbrace B\in\mathcal B(\mathcal H)\,|\,\operatorname{tr}(B^\dagger B)<\infty\rbrace\subset\mathcal B(\mathcal H)
$$

which form a Hilbert space under the scalar product $\langle A,B\rangle=\operatorname{tr}(A^\dagger B)$ *(this can be seen as the "natural extension" of matrices to infinite-dimensions in some sense)*. Then we can use the trace argument from finite-dimensions as for $T,S\in\mathcal B_2(\mathcal H)$ now $TS=\lambda ST$ for some $\lambda\in\mathbb C$ together with $\operatorname{tr}(TS)\neq0$ implies

$$
\operatorname{tr}(TS)=\operatorname{tr}(\lambda ST)=\lambda \operatorname{tr}(ST)=\lambda \operatorname{tr}(TS)\ \Rightarrow\ \lambda=1
$$

so $T$ and $S$ commute.

---

As an introduction to the trace on infinite-dimensional Hilbert spaces, Hilbert-Schmidt operators etc. I recommend Chapter 3.4 of the book ["Analysis Now" (1989) by Pedersen](https://www.springer.com/de/book/9780387967882).

Comment: what if $\operatorname{tr}(TS)=0$?

Comment: @YuriiSavchuk I think that if $S,T \geq 0$  is a sufficient condition for $S$ and $T$ to commute if they are $\lambda$-commute, but is this condition necessary?

Comment: @Schüler No, it is not necessary. Consider for example the relation $X^*X=qXX^*$, which has no non-zero bounded solutions for $q\neq 1$. I.e. $X^*X=qXX^*$ for bounded operators implies $q=1$.

Comment: @Schüler Can you state your question as a conjecture (theorem) which you think might be true? Namely, the "sufficient part".